# Problem about the definition of Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the definition of domain, we first define a degree function $\vartheta: R^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with such two constraints:

(1) $\vartheta(f)\leq \vartheta(fg)$ for all $f,g\in R^\times$.

(2) for all $f,g\in R$ with $f\in R^\times$, there exist $q,r\in R$ with $g=qf+r$ and either $r=0$ or $\vartheta(r)<\vartheta(f)$.

I wonder why we need the first constraints? I think with only the second constraint, it is enough to prove the theorem: every Euclidean ring is a PID.

Can anyone give me a example where the first constraint is used?

Comment: Wikipedia indeed says the first constraint is unnecessary in a certain sense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition However, dropping it doesn't give you any extra generality.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, thank you!

Comment: A quibble: usually $R^\times$ would mean the _units_ in a ring $R$, but here probably you just mean non-zero elements...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my [sci.math post on 2009/7/2:](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8zk52ra7te.fsf@nestle.csail.mit.edu) The  property  $\rm V(a) \le V(ab)$  needn't be assumed in order
to deduce all of the basic properties of Euclidean domains, since any Euclidean function [can be normalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030111/242) to satisfy said property
by defining  $\rm\:v(a) = min\: V(aD^*),\ D* = D\backslash0.\:$  This fact is so well-known it is
even in the Wikipedia  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain.

See also the analogous [Dedekind-Hasse criterion](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8z3awla74e.fsf%40nestle.csail.mit.edu) for a PID.
And see also [this paper[1]](https://aj.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf) which gives an *in-depth* study and comparison of a dozen different definitions/axioms for Euclidean *rings.*

[1] [Euclidean Rings.](https://aj.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf) A. G. Agargun, C. R. Fletcher
Turkish J. of Mathematics, 19, 1995, 291 - 299.