# Manipulations of Euclidean domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I am trying to answer the following question

[image]

For (a) I have said that a and ab are in the ring R, by the definition of a ring. Therefore, by the definition of a Euclidean domain a=abq+r. As we are told that r is non-zero, we know that $\delta(r)<\delta(ab)$.

For (b) I am less sure how to prove this. We know that $\delta(r)<\delta(ab)$ and $\delta(ab)\ge\delta(b)$, but I'm not sure how to show what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a), you are not given that $r \neq 0$, you need to show this. By definition of an Euclidean domain, you can find $q,r \in R$ but either $r=0$ or $\delta(r) < \delta(ab)$. Suppose $r=0$, then $a=abq$ which implies since $a \neq 0$ and you are in an integral domain that $1=bq$, but that means $b$ is invertible (a contradiction). So $r \neq 0$.

For b), we have $r=a-abq=a(1-bq)$ so $\delta(a) \leq \delta(r)$.

Comment: Can you expand on why a(1-bq) implies result?

Comment: For an Euclidean valuation/function, $\delta(x)\leq \delta(xy)$ for any nonzero $x,y \in R$. So $\delta(a) \leq \delta(a(1-bq))=\delta(r)$.

Comment: @user43290 The property used in the prior comment need not necessarily hold true, so check you definitions. One can however always choose some $\delta$ for which it is true, e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143127/242)

Comment: I wonder how you would show b) without assuming the valuation had that property.