# Is the quotient by a unit in an euclidean domain unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

I've seen some conditions for quotients and reminders to be unique, though they are not in general. However I haven't been able to find a counter example for the case when "dividing" by a unit. In this case, is the quotient and reminder unique? ($a=a\times u+0$, where $u$ is a unit).

For my defintion of euclidean domain I'm using Aluffi's:
[image]

Comment: I think it must be unique if $1$ is defined to be the multiplicative identity and $0$ is the additive identity.

Comment: There are [many different definitions of Euclidean domains](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143127/242). Please supply the precise definition you are using

Comment: What you might want to ask is "is the quotient by a unit in a euclidean domain unique?" 1 is an ambiguous word. Rings do not concern themselves with multiplicative identities, but rather with units, which are more general.

Comment: thank you all, I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: What is the definition of "valuation" being used in that definition? (and what is footnote $8$?)

Comment: @BillDubuque A valuation is just a function from $R \setminus 0$ to the non-negative integers. Footnote 8 just points out that $v(b)\leq v(ab)$ is sometimes required but not really needed.